# Find the sum of these two angles.

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I’m not sure if I’ve done this correctly. The answer I got is 12.5 degrees. Help would be much appreciated.

This is how I got it:

1. Found the missing side of CAD
2. Found half of CAD
3. Found GAF (I labeled the upper point of the straight line at the very center G)
4. Found EAF
5. EAF-CAD = 12.5

This is the problem:

A penalty kick is taken from the center of the penalty area at position A (see image). The goalkeeper stands in the center of the goal and can thus block a shot anywhere along segment CD. To score, the shooter must kick the ball within the angle CAE or angle DAF. Find the sum of these two angles to the nearest tenth of a degree.

The image associated with the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC8h4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be where the goalie stands. Then $\angle EAC=\angle EAG-\angle CAG$.

If I read the dimensions correctly, we have $\tan(\angle EAG)=\frac{12}{54}$ and $\tan(\angle CAG)=\frac{6}{54}$.

Using the calculator, you can now find $\angle EAG$ and $\angle CAG$, and hence $\angle EAC$. Now double the result. The answer will be close to the one you got, but not exactly the same.

Comment: 12.4 degrees? Did you get that, too? It seems like I made a small error the first time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. To one decimal place, that's what I got.

Answer (score 0):

Deduce that $EC = DF = 6' $ since $24 - 12 = 12$ and $\frac {12}{2} = 6$. You can then add up those lengths to find the distance from the goalie to either side of the goal. Knowing that A is $54'$ from the goalie, use a tangent function for each one to the nearest tenth of a degree and add them up. Make sure your calculator is programmed for degrees, too, otherwise you'll get something in radians or something else.